# Index advise SQL Server 500M records

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, database-administration

I have a table with the following structure:

```
primary+foreignkey1
primary+foreignkey2
primary+foreignkey3
primary+foreignkey4
primary+foreignkey5
primary+foreignkey6
string
int
varbinary
```

It very much acts like a fact table, in which the foreign keys reference dimensions. The dimensions are very small, around 2000 rows each. The main fact table however has 500 million rows.

Currently, the performance is very very bad. Simple queries take a long time. The data changes every 2 years, so it is very static.

We currently only have a clustered index on the all pk values:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
    [id1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id5] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id6] [int] NOT NULL,
    [location] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [year] smallint NOT NULL,
    [text] [decimal](10, 4) NULL,
    [hash] [varbinary](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    id1 ASC,
    id2 ASC,
    id3 ASC,
    id4 ASC,
    id5 ASC,
    id6 ASC,
    location ASC,
    year asc

)
```

Could anyone advise me in a best practice index to optimize performance when querying the table?

Comment: Indexes are used to optimize queries.  You need to have some idea of how the table will be used.

Comment: What version of SQL Server ? for 2014+ (2016+ preferably), for this kind of fact tables and if you do not have a clear querying pattern you can use a non clustered columnstore index (this is why they are buit)

Comment: plus one to Bogdan's comment, However I would go with a Clustered ColumnStore Index

Comment: we are using sql server 2016, so we can use either. Which would be best? Clustered or nonclustered columnstore index?

Comment: @ImperialBert, (imho) Clustered, it was built to be pretty efficient for star schema workloads. Also, it will make that fact table 5-20x smaller. The drawback - foreign keys limitations.. they are possible but require extra btree indexes

Comment: Also, if your dimensions up to 2000 rows, consider changing FK columns to SMALLINT.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: this post is based on personal opinion)

**Firstly**, your clustered primary key looks slightly meaningless:

```
CONSTRAINT [pk_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    id1 ASC,
    id2 ASC,
    id3 ASC,
    id4 ASC,
    id5 ASC,
    id6 ASC,
    location ASC,
    year asc
)
```

- It hardly warranties any uniqueness, because nearly all columns are placed there,
- it slows down inserts
- it makes all other nonclustered indexes also meaningless because they will contain all those listed columns of the clustered index in all non-clustered indexes.
- It can be more or less helpful only by searching values on column `id1`

**Secondly**, without seeing your queries it is hard to make any conclusions except that obviously, you have a star schema datamart. 
Microsoft introduced Column store indexes for such kind of analytical workload.

To emphasize said above, Clustered Columnstore indexes are created by default on Azure SQL Datawarehouse tables, so it really shines bright in case of aggregations on large datasets

Therefore, due to a star schema, amount of rows and obvious analytic workload, just **a generic advice**:

- Consider trying a clustered column store index on a fact table. It will be a single index on it, but it covers all columns
- Consider maintaining referential integrity on the ETL side.